# How to show only 3 div in one row and another 3 div in another row

Tags: css, angular, typescript

[This is the actual design I need to achieve, having 3 divs in a row and another 3 in next row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgeTe.jpg)

[Instead I'm having this kind of div, can anyone help me to achieve the above styling ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr1XT.jpg)

MY HTML :

```
    <div class="category-food">
        <div class="food-item" *ngFor="let art of meals">
            <img class="card-img-top center" [src]="art.strMealThumb" style="max-width:300px;" role="button">
            <div>
                <h1 class="content-text">{{art.strMeal}}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

STYLE SHEET :

I have tried the below styling to achieve the expected output but I didn't get the actual output

```
    .category-food {
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .category-food .food-item {
      align-items: center;
      margin: 20px;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid grey;
    }
    
    .card-img-top {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 50%;
      border-radius: 6px;
    }
    
    .content-text {
      font-size: 24px !important;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: where are the 6 divs in your html? What class is associated with the divs you want organized?

Comment: @john the Image and the text is dynamic value, we might even have many values so I want to organize 3 dynamic values in one row and another 3 in next row and so on

Comment: That's what I assumed, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So assuming that `.food-item`is the div in question that you have 6 of, you can achive this using `display: grid;` on the parent container of all of those `div` which would be `.category-food`

So adding this:

```
 .category-food {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    }
```

to your CSS (i've also copied and pasted the `.food-item` div 6 times since you provided code didn't have 6 divs. This is what you get:

```css
.category-food {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
      gap: 50px 50px;
      margin: 20px;
    }
    
    .category-food .food-item {
      align-items: center;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid grey;
    }
    
    .card-img-top {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 50%;
      border-radius: 6px;
    }
    
    .content-text {
      font-size: 24px !important;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="category-food">
        <div class="food-item" *ngFor="let art of meals">
            <img class="card-img-top center" [src]="art.strMealThumb" style="max-width:300px;" role="button">
            <div>
                <h1 class="content-text">{{art.strMeal}}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
               <div class="food-item" *ngFor="let art of meals">
            <img class="card-img-top center" [src]="art.strMealThumb" style="max-width:300px;" role="button">
            <div>
                <h1 class="content-text">{{art.strMeal}}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
               <div class="food-item" *ngFor="let art of meals">
            <img class="card-img-top center" [src]="art.strMealThumb" style="max-width:300px;" role="button">
            <div>
                <h1 class="content-text">{{art.strMeal}}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
               <div class="food-item" *ngFor="let art of meals">
            <img class="card-img-top center" [src]="art.strMealThumb" style="max-width:300px;" role="button">
            <div>
                <h1 class="content-text">{{art.strMeal}}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
               <div class="food-item" *ngFor="let art of meals">
            <img class="card-img-top center" [src]="art.strMealThumb" style="max-width:300px;" role="button">
            <div>
                <h1 class="content-text">{{art.strMeal}}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
               <div class="food-item" *ngFor="let art of meals">
            <img class="card-img-top center" [src]="art.strMealThumb" style="max-width:300px;" role="button">
            <div>
                <h1 class="content-text">{{art.strMeal}}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Now I do have 3 divs in one row but I don't see any spacing in between them, If you check the image that I have uploaded you can see there's a spacing in between divs

Comment: simply add a gap using `gap: 50px 50px;` for example and adding it to `.category-food` I will update my answer

Comment: Yeah Thanks John, just another thing we don't see the exact spacing on the right as we do have on the left. on the right its aligned to the screen no spacing as like we do have in the left, is there any solution for that ?

Comment: You have `margin: 20px;` under `.category-food .food-item` I would remove the margin from there and add it to JUST `.category-food`. I will update my answer again.